# Intel XDK - Input Hidden

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

Estou aprendendo a usar o Intel XDK.
Preciso criar um campo oculto onde terá informações do dispositivo. No html usamos `hidden`, mas esse comando não é aceito no XDK, ou estou fazendo algo errado.

Código:

```
<label class="item item-input widget uib_w_6 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="dispositivo">
                <input type="text">
            </label>
```

Se eu coloco o `hidden` de forma manual, ele não aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isso sem colocar o atributo "hidden" diretamente no seu HTML.

Se você quer fazer com JavaScript puro, pode ser da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("seuEelemento").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Se você puder usar jQuery (não sei se é possivel), pode ficar dessa forma:

```
$("#seuEelemento").hide();
```

Caso você queira saber mais, ou tenha alguma dúvida, segue algumas documentações:

HTML DOM Style Visibility: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

jQuery .hide: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

Cara, provavelmente o CSS de alguma das classes está interferindo no layout do input.

```
<label data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="dispositivo">
    <input class="text-input" type="hidden">
</label>
```

Eu fiz isso e deu certo, se eu troco por text, ele aparece, se coloco o ***hidden*** ele fica oculto, mas aparece no **Inspecionar Elemento** do Browser.
E complementando a resposta do Nikofoxxx, é possível usar Jquery desde que você esteja chamando o arquivo, como em qualquer HTML.